# Add dropdown to settings charm in Windows 8 Metro (C#)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I found how can I add command (looks like link) to settings charm:

```
SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += MainPage_CommandsRequested;

        void MainPage_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var cmd = new SettingsCommand("feedback", "Send feedback", new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommandInvokedHandler(x =>
            {
                App.ShowSendFeedback();
            }));

            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Clear();
            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(cmd);
        }
```

Now I need adding dropdown list for language selection to settings charm. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add it directly to the Win8 UI.  The idea is to publish 'command' links into the Win8 UI and then, when they are clicked, your app gets notified.  At that point, you show your own UI with whatever widgets you want in it.  See any of the Settings samples in the SDK for an example.

Answer (score 3):

See also [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/04/22/integrating-with-windows-8-settings-charm.aspx), which explains how you can display a custom user control whenever one of your settings are selected.

Basically, he moves an off-screen user control on-screen and then hides it again when user interaction is done. To me this feels kind of hack-ish... But I guess that's where WinRT is right now.